# javascript: Fetch and display youtube thumbnail in real time when user types a url

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I am making a web app with React frontend. There is a url input box and below it is a img display panel. What i want to do is, when a user types a youtube url in the input box, the thumbnail of the video should automatically display in the img panel below. I have made a function for fetching youtube thumbnail like this

```js
fetchYouTube(event) {
  const state = this.state;
  state[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
  this.setState(state);

  function getImageThumbnail(state) {
    var videoid = state.match(/(?:https?:\/{2})?(?:w{3}\.)?youtu(?:be)?\.(?:com|be)(?:\/watch\?v=|\/)([^\s&]+)/);
    if (videoid != null) {
      this.setState({
        ytimage: `https://img.youtube.com/vi/${videoid[1]}/0.jpg`
      });
      return this.state.ytimage;
    } else {
      return "invalid video id";
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the place which takes and displays the thumbnail

```html
<div className="col-md-6 no-padding">
  <input type="text" name="preview_video" value={preview_video} onChange={this.handleChange} id="defaultFormSubscriptionNameEx" className="form-control" placeholder="Preview Video Url" />
  <div className="Video-review">
    <img src={this.state.ytimage} onChange={this.fetchYouTube.bind(this)} />
  </div>
</div>
```

How can i achieve this feature? and what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
import axios from 'axios'
class Hello extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        ytimage: null
    }
}

 getVideoId(){
   let tempVar = this.typedUrl
   return tempVar.split("?v=")[1] 
 }

fetchYouTube(){
       let thumbnailUrl = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/"+this.getVideoId()+"/0.jpg"
       this.setState({ytimage: thumbnailUrl}) 


}

handleChange(e){
    let typedUrl = e.target.value
    this.typedUrl = e.target.value
}

render() {

    return (

        <div> For Demo purpose
          <div className="col-md-6 no-padding">
            <input type="text" name="preview_video"
                   onBlur ={this.fetchYouTube.bind(this)}
                   onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                   className="form-control" placeholder="Preview Video Url" />

          </div>

          <img src={this.state.ytimage} />

        </div>
    )

}
   }


ReactDOM.render(
     <Hello name="World" />,
     document.getElementById('container')
 );
```

Comment: Where is it fetching the thumbnail?

Comment: @BarryBonds have updated the code try it .. usually you can access youtube thumbnail from this url `https://img.youtube.com/vi/<youtube-video-id>/0.jpg` or 1.jpg or 2.jpg or 3.jpg